# how do I access a specific value in a tensor?

Tags: python, keras, tensor

I have an input layer `wtm=Input(4,4,1)` and I want to access each value of this layer during learning. for accessing to `wtm[1,1]`( the value in row=1 and column=1) I use this code `a=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[1,1])(wtm)` but the output shape is `TensorShape([Dimension(4), Dimension(1)])` not (1,1) and I think it gives the first column.is it right? if I only need one value in specific row and column what should I do and how can I change it? I really need your help. I know this could be easy but I am a beginner and do not know how to work with this issue:(
**Edit:**
suppose

```
wtm=
1 0 0 1
1 1 1 0
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 1
```

we know wtm(0,0)=1 now I want to produce new tensor with `shape (28,28,1)` with value 1 and I want to do this for all values in wtm.

```
 wtm=Input((4,4,1))
    image = Input((28, 28, 1))
    conv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl1e')(image)
    conv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl2e')(conv1)
    conv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same', name='convl3e')(conv2)
    BN=BatchNormalization()(conv3)
    encoded =  Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='encoded_I')(BN)

   rep=Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:Kr.backend.repeat(x,28))
    a=rep(Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[1,1])(wtm))

    add_const = Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x: x[0] + x[1])
    encoded_merged = add_const([encoded,a])


    #-----------------------decoder------------------------------------------------
    #------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    deconv1 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl1d')(encoded_merged)
    deconv2 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same', name='convl2d')(deconv1)
    deconv3 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl3d')(deconv2)
    deconv4 = Conv2D(64, (5, 5), activation='elu',padding='same', name='convl4d')(deconv3)
    BNd=BatchNormalization()(deconv4)
    #DrO2=Dropout(0.25,name='DrO2')(BNd)

    decoded = Conv2D(1, (5, 5), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='decoder_output')(BNd) 
    #model=Model(inputs=image,outputs=decoded)

    model=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=decoded)

    decoded_noise = GaussianNoise(0.5)(decoded)

    #----------------------w extraction------------------------------------
    convw1 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl1w')(decoded_noise)#24
    convw2 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='convl2w')(convw1)#20
    #Avw1=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(convw2)
    convw3 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl3w')(convw2)#16
    convw4 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu' ,name='conl4w')(convw3)#12
    #Avw2=AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(convw4)
    convw5 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl5w')(convw4)#8
    convw6 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', name='conl6w')(convw5)#4
    convw7 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl7w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw6)#4
    convw8 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu', padding='same',name='conl8w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw7)#4
    convw9 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl9w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw8)#4
    convw10 = Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',padding='same', name='conl10w',dilation_rate=(2,2))(convw9)#4
    BNed=BatchNormalization()(convw10)
    pred_w = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid', padding='same', name='reconstructed_W',dilation_rate=(2,2))(BNed)  

    w_extraction=Model(inputs=[image,wtm],outputs=[decoded,pred_w])

    w_extraction.summary()
```

Comment: Can you please show us a [mcve] of what you have tried so far?

Comment: I put the complete code above but my problem is the part I said before and I do not know can I access each value in tensor?

Comment: why the output shape of this code Kr.layers.Lambda(lambda x:x[1,1])(wtm) is (4,1)? I think it should be (1,1). what is the problem?

Comment: Can you create a smaller example of what you are trying to accomplish, please? It's quite difficult to see from your long code snippet what exactly you're asking. Also, please include all necessary import statements so that we can run the code on our own systems.

Comment: I add an example that shows what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're not taking into account that the first dimension is the batch dimension.

If you run

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda

def inspector(x):
    print(x.shape)
    return x

inp = Input((4, 4, 1))
lmb = Lambda(inspector)(inp)
```

you will see that it prints

```
(?, 4, 4, 1)
(?, 4, 4, 1)
```

indicating that `x` is four-dimensional.

Comment: I know the first dimension is batch and the second and third dimension are the size of the image and the last one is the number of the channel that is here my images are gray and so it will be 1, but I need to access the values of the image for each sample in the batch.

Comment: I suggest you try to work your way forward from here, carefully checking the dimensions. If I'm not mistaken, `x[1]` will return the first entry of the batch, hence `x[1, 1]` will (as you discovered) return a (4,1)-dimensional tensor.

Comment: could you answer me this question? suppose wtm is the same as the example I put above. and if we consider wtm as an image with size 4x4 the wtm( 0,0) is 1. now if we consier wtm=Input( 4,4,1), what is the value of wtm[:,0,0,:]? is it 1 or not?